# How can we implement delete operation using dropwizard web serivce

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I read many blog and tutorial, but i didn't find delete operation in dropwizard web services.

Here is my code:

```
public class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> {
    public PersonDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }
    public Optional<Person> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
    }

    public Person create(Person person) {
        return persist(person);
    }

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll"));
    }
    //here i want to create delete method
}
```

here is my service file:

```
@Path("/people")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PeopleResource {

    private final PersonDAO peopleDAO;

    public PeopleResource(PersonDAO peopleDAO) {
        this.peopleDAO = peopleDAO;
    }

    @POST
    @UnitOfWork
    public Person createPerson(Person person) {
        return peopleDAO.create(person);
    }

    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<Person> listPeople() {
        return peopleDAO.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Optional<Person> getUser(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        Optional<Person> person = peopleDAO.findPeopleById(id);
        return person;
    }
    //here i add to delete method that call to dao class
}
```

If anyone have an idea please suggest me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Try to do in DAO:

```
public void delete(Person person){
        currentSession().delete(person);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using a `@DELETE` method?

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{id}")
public void delete(@PathParam("id") IntParam id) {
  peopleDAO.deleteById(id.get());
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i need PersonDAO file code for delete record from database.

Comment: @MehulDudhat -  You can use `AbstractDAO`'s `currentSession` method to get a handle to a `Session` object which you can then use to delete the entity.